# Nodejs: How to set limit when using Request module for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently I am having some trouble with implementing a query limit for my mongodb when using the request module. I do have some queries which I stringify and attach to the URL which is being requested. However, setting a limit of how many results should be shown (as explained in the mongodb doc: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html (see option)) is not doing the trick or at least I am putting it in the wrong place...

```
//request all countries that are in the database and push them into a search array

var query = JSON.stringify({'createdDate': {$gte: moment().subtract(5, 'days')}});

request(db_url + 'countries/?' + query, function(error, response, body) {}
```

trying to add:

```
var querylimit = {"limit": 20}
```

The mongodb doc gives the following example:

```
var options = {
"limit": 20,
"skip": 10,
"sort": "title"
}

collection.find({}, options).toArray(...);
```

Tried to add the querylimit behind the query (+query, querylimit), already in the stringify, stringified it itself and tried to add it etc.

I just cannot find a way to limit the query when using the request module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like the following:

```
var limit = 20;
request(db_url + 'countries/?' + encodeURIComponent(query + "&limit=" + limit), function(error, response, body) {}
```

You are just appending the query options to the end of the URI.

Comment: Hey Joe,
ok, I get what you are trying to do. My result however looks like this:
mydomain/countries/?{%22createdDate%22:{%22$gte%22:%222016-08-18T19:37:33.120Z%22}}&limit=20

this is not looking correct and it doesnt result in the expected outcome. All queries are applied, except for the limit.. Any idea?

Comment: ah, right. Try wrapping that addition in encodeURIComponent. I've updated the answer

Comment: hm, still all results showing up. the query looks like this now:
{"createdDate":{"$gte":"2016-08-18T20:08:36.883Z"}}%26limit%3D20

Comment: encodeURIComponent on both the query and the options. I think the formatting is confusing the request module.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow @Jan173

You can't contact new object to stringified object.

Instead you can convert your string to object using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and add your query limit into the same object

```
var queryObj = JSON.parse(query); // stringify query converted to object
queryObj.limit = 20; // adding new propery limit to query object
collection.find({}, queryObj); // fetch data with query object
```

Hope this will work, Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi keviveks, I somehow dont undestand your answer. I try to build a query to GET the results from the db. With the code I posted above I get a connection timeout, as the array is too long (500k objects). I need to only grab the first 20 from the db to not get the timeout.

As I understand you, you assume I already got the array from the db and try to cut it then?